# I want Powershell to return computer names that have a specific program installed

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am trying to query computers within my AD environment for a specific program for it to return names of the computers that have that program installed. For example, PC-Name | Program name.

```
$MyPC = get-adcomputer -filter * | select -property name


foreach($PC in $MyPC){Get-ItemProperty "hklm:\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Adobe\Acrobat Reader" | select name,PSChildName} format-table -AutoSize

$MyPC
```

Comment: So you're querying to get all computers in your domain and then for each computer you're querying the same registry key (your local one)

Comment: I thought that the "foreach" would query the local reg of each computer?

Comment: What makes you think that. It doesn't.

Comment: I thought I was telling powershell to basically, look for a specific program and return if its found in its local reg. Is there an alternative ?

Comment: Assuming you have permissions, you can use `Invoke-Command`, in parallel preferably

Comment: When you say "invoke-command' where would I place that within foreach ? or would I have to write this differently?

Comment: @Briel95 look for this site http://vcloud-lab.com/entries/powershell/powershell-get-registry-value-data   Invoke-Command -ComputerName

Comment: Take a look at the built-in help, `Get-Help Invoke-Command`. Will show you its uses, syntax, and about the individual parameters.